# How to simplify querySelectorAll parameter using value of another querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have the following:

```
var searchSuggestionsItems = document.querySelectorAll("#search-user-results .live-search-results--list li");
```

And want to use this selector for select all `a` elements that have `.overedSuggestion` class. I know that the following should work:

```
var selectedSuggestion = document.querySelectorAll("#search-user-results .live-search-results--list li a.overedSuggestion");
```

But I'm looking for a simplified way to do. What I tried:

```
selectedSuggestion = document.querySelectorAll(searchSuggestionsItems+' a.overedSuggestion');
```

this returns the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object NodeList] a.overedSuggestion' is not a valid selector.
```

Comment: You can not just "add" a string to the _result_ of querySelectorAll. As the error message tells you it is a NodeList, and concatenating that with a string makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: check this documentation `element.querySelector()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are concatenating a `NodeList` collection with a string. The `NodeList` is converted to `[object NodeList]` string which is not a valid/meaningful selector.

DOM elements also have `.querySelectorAll` method, so you can code:

```
searchSuggestionsItems[0].querySelectorAll('a.overedSuggestion');
```

The above code snippet returns `a.overedSuggestion` descendants of the first element in the node list. For getting descendants of all the elements in the list you need to iterate through the list which is not efficient. Using a longer selector is more efficient.

Your code would work if `searchSuggestionsItems` was a selector, i.e.:

```
var searchSuggestionsItems = "#search-user-results .live-search-results--list li";
```